# Primary key column not auto incrementing

Tags: spring, hibernate

How to properly do auto incrementing?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="userid", updatable=false, nullable=false)
private Integer userid;
```

I am having a problem with hibernate annotation, when I create the database with the annotations on the columns. The issue is that when I insert a row the database doesn't auto increment the userid column. Which then throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Yeah I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate support different strategies to generate pk values. 
One of them is the identity strategy which uses an auto-incremented database column.

If you need to follow this way,you need to annotate the pk attribute @Id and with the @GeneratedValue annotation and strategy as GenerationType.IDENTITY.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer userid;
```